# Render bottom tab with persistent action sheet

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am trying to achieve the following layout inside my app:

[image]

Basically render the content of my `<BottomTabNavigator/>` inside a bottom sheet while a map is always rendered as a screen in the back. As you tab around the bottom-sheet stays put but the content changes.

I am using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) and [@gorhom/bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet)

I am able to achieve this but would like some guidance on how to properly set this up using react-navigation.

I haven't found an official guide or anything so I looked up online and some people mention creating a **custom** tab bar that renders a BottomSheet on top (This is how I am able to achieve this layout). Something like this:

```js
const CustomTabBar = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <BottomSheet
         snapPoints = {[450, 300, 0]}
         renderContent = {this.renderInner}
         renderHeader = {this.renderHeader}
       />
      <BottomTabBar {...props} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I would then do conditional rendering inside the modal to display the different screens. This does feel a bit hacky and typing the navigation and state props is a nightmare.

Is there a better way to do this?

I have tried wrapping my `<BottomTab />` inside the `<BottomSheet />` but that doesn't seem to work.

Is the custom tab bar the right way to do this?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to show this bottom sheet in all the tabs or inside the particular tab only?

Comment: All tabs! @VickyAhuja Basically the same layout as the FindMy app of iOS

Comment: i guess one should not make bottom tab bar heavy by adding bottom sheet, instead we should put this inside our screen may be we can have reusable component of that so we can reuse with minimal amount of code inside screen.

Comment: I mean the logic that the bottom sheet would have is just to render the diff screens. It being 'heavy' shouldn't affect the perfomance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As here the custom tabbar has bottom sheet it will be same for all the tab screens and can also make performance issues if we manage the bottom sheet states in the custom bottom tab component.

Have a try with the below example to achieve the same functionality as shown in the above image.

```
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useImperativeHandle,
  useMemo,
  useRef,
} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';
import {GestureHandlerRootView} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const BottomTab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const CustomBottomSheet = forwardRef((myProps, ref) => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // variables
  const snapPoints = useMemo(() => ['25%'], []);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => {
      return {
        open: () => {
          bottomSheetRef.current?.expand();
        },
        close: () => {
          bottomSheetRef.current?.close();
        },
      };
    },
    [],
  );

  return (
    <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} snapPoints={snapPoints}>
      <View style={styles.centeredContent}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{`inside ${myProps.name}`}</Text>
      </View>
    </BottomSheet>
  );
});

const TabComponent = (props: any) => {
  const customBottomSheetRef = useRef<any>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    customBottomSheetRef.current?.open();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.centeredContent}>
      <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{props.route.name}</Text>
      <CustomBottomSheet ref={customBottomSheetRef} name={props.route.name} />
    </View>
  );
};

function App(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <SafeAreaProvider style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <BottomTab.Navigator>
            <BottomTab.Screen name="home" component={TabComponent} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name="search" component={TabComponent} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name="explore" component={TabComponent} />
            <BottomTab.Screen name="profile" component={TabComponent} />
          </BottomTab.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  safeAreaContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  centeredContent: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default App;
```

OUTPUT:

[image: CODE SNIPPET OUTPUT IMAGE]

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for this implementation - my only remaining question is to why you think managing the state inside the custom tab bar will lead to performance issues?

Comment: @WalterMonecke Good Question, Actually whenever your bottom sheet content or any state inside custom bottom tab changes it will re-render all the code inside the custom bottom tab. That's why it can lead performance issues.